# Uncaught ReferenceError: Handler is not defined

Tags: c#, extjs, handlers

I get this error using c# handlers (.ashx) :

> ProviderGrid.js:23 Uncaught ReferenceError: Handler is not defined

Here it's my handler file :

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="dashVidence.Handler" %>

using System;
using System.Web;

namespace dashVidence
{

    public class Handler : IHttpHandler
    {
//ReturnProvider contain a method returning string datas
        ReturnProvider rp = new ReturnProvider();
        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {

        }

        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public string provider()
        {
            return rp.getProvidersList();
        }

    }
}
```

The handler file is referenced in the aspx file

Comment: Think your tags might be wrong, this doesn't have anything to do with extjs.

Comment: That's a javascript error, right? Where's your javascript?

Comment: what is line 23 of ProviderGrid.js?

Comment: I'm using extjs 4 to write the javascript code, the line 23 is :var test= new Handler(); (when i'm trying to instantiate the handler class the project didn't recognize it)

Answer (score -1):

> Please add debugger; to this line.

```
 $(function () {
>         debugger;   <------------------HERE
>         $('#feedbackform').submit(function () {
```

now in browser right click inspect element and go to the console tab. if you do not hit this line onload turn

> debugging on in your web.configuration.
>
> hit submit. if you hit the line just go through it line by line and
>   the offending line will throw a error.
>
> if it just throws a error like the image below. Sorry not enough rep
>   points to post image directly. :(
>
> http://postimg.org/image/5ke0jd6xv/
>
> then it is the line above other wise check out the stack.
>
> Hope this helps

Quoting my self is amazing :)

though what you do is when the error fails insert the debugger on the level above it.
Mind you this is a javascript error